# CFBundleDevelopmentRegion not working

Tags: ios7, localization

I've added several localizations to my app.

- English
- Japanese
- zh-hans
- zh-hant

and I set value "English" in the key CFBundleDevelopmentRegion at info.plist file.

When download app on iOS7 and I change system language from Japanese
to other language (ex. korea), my app show me Japanese.
Another, When change from zh-hans to other language,
my app show me Japanese.

It is not expected and It happen only iOS7.

How to set default language on iOS7 ?